# error al mandar un metodo post en nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs, typescript

Tengo un error al momento de mandar un método post por async await estoy usando el npm mysql2 pero al usar async tengo el siguiente error:
you have tried to call .then(), .catch(), or invoked await on the result of query that is not a promise, which is a programming error. Try calling con.promise().query(), or require('mysql2/promise') instead of 'mysql2'

//metodo post llamado create

```
 public async  create(req:Request,res:Response){
 
  /*  pool.query( (`INSERT INTO productos (nombre_producto,
      categoria_producto,precio_producto,descripbr_producto,imagen) VALUES 
  ('${req.body.nombre_producto}', '${req.body.categoria_producto}',
   '${ req.body.precio_producto}','${req.body.descripbr_producto}',
   '${req.body.imagen}')`)); */


 
      await pool.query( (`INSERT INTO productos (nombre_producto,
           categoria_producto,precio_producto,descripbr_producto,imagen) VALUES 
       ('${req.body.nombre_producto}', '${req.body.categoria_producto}',
        '${ req.body.precio_producto}','${req.body.descripbr_producto}',
        '${req.body.imagen}')`));


  
     res.json({message:'creando'}); 
}
```

Comment: ¿Intentaste con las sugerencias que te da textualmente el error? ¿Haciendo `require('mysql2/promise')` en donde declaras el pool o con `con.promise().query()`? ¿Cuál es el resultado?

Answer (score 1):

Quizás deberías remover los parentesis adicionales que tiene, debería quedar:

```
await pool.query(`INSERT INTO productos (nombre_producto,
 categoria_producto,precio_producto,descripbr_producto,imagen) VALUES 
('${req.body.nombre_producto}', '${req.body.categoria_producto}',
'${req.body.precio_producto}','${req.body.descripbr_producto}',
'${req.body.imagen}')`);
```